# how to convert index array to associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like that

```
$products = array(array(354),array(1),array(375),array(1),array(344),array(2));
```

and i want to achieve array like that

```
$arrProducts= array(array('product_id'=>354,'qty'=>1),array('product_id'=>375,'qty'=>1),array('product_id'=>344,'qty'=>2));
```

I achieved this array using this code

```
foreach($products as $val)
{
  $abc[] =$val[0];

}

for($i=0;$i<count($abc);$i++)
{
  if($i%2==0)
  {
    $newarr[]['product_id'] = $abc[$i];
  }
  else{
     $newarr[]['qty'] = $abc[$i];
  }
}


for($j=0;$j<count($newarr);$j++)
{
  if($j%2==0)
  {
      $arrProducts[] = array_merge($newarr[$j],$newarr[$j+1]);
  }
  else{
     continue;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrProducts);
```

but i think my way to get this array is too long so how can i get this array in short way using some array functions or should i use this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk` in this case if this is always by twos, and combine it with `array_combine()`:

```
$products = array(array(354),array(1),array(375),array(1),array(344),array(2));
$products = array_chunk($products, 2);

$arrProducts = array();
$keys = array('product_id', 'qty');
foreach($products as $val) {
    $arrProducts[] = array_combine($keys, array(reset($val[0]), reset($val[1])));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrProducts);
```

Another alternative would be:

```
$products = array(array(354),array(1),array(375),array(1),array(344),array(2));
$keys = array('product_id', 'qty');
$arrProducts = array_map(function($e) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, array_map('reset', $e));
}, array_chunk($products, 2));
```

This will yield the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Consume two array elements on each iteration:

```php
$arrProducts = array();
$inputLength = count($products);
for ($i = 0; $i < $inputLength; $i += 2) {
    $arrProducts[] = array('product_id' => $products[$i][0], 'qty' => $products[$i+1][0]);
}
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it. No need to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=1;
$j=0;
foreach($products as $val)
{
if(($i%2) == 0) 
{       
  $abc[$j]['qty'] =$val[0];
  $j++;
}
else
{
 $abc[$j]['product_id'] =$val[0];   
}
$i++;
}
```